# Save fieldname and fieldvalues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to save all the values, field names of any table in a table.

Target Table:TARGETTABLE

Source Table:MYSOURCETABLE

I want to run as follows:

```
exec FieldveValueWrite("MYSOURCETABLE") 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TARGETTABLE](
[Fieldname] [nchar](50) NULL,
[FieldValue] [nchar](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Output will be as follows:

```
[Fieldname] [FieldValue] 
name VEDAT
surname PALA
city TOKAT
counrty TÜRKİYE
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer for same question:

```
declare @TableName varchar(50) = 'MYSOURCETABLE';

declare @Columns varchar(4000) = '';
declare @InsertValues varchar(4000) = '';
declare @ColumnsVar varchar(4000) = '';
declare @SQL varchar(max);

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
SELECT @InsertValues = @InsertValues + '(''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''',@' + COLUMN_NAME + '),' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName

SET @ColumnsVar = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Columns,'[','@'),']',',');
SET @ColumnsVar = LEFT(@ColumnsVar, LEN(@ColumnsVar)-1);

SET @InsertValues = LEFT(@InsertValues, LEN(@InsertValues)-1);

SET @SQL = @Columns;
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'[','DECLARE @');
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,']',' nvarchar(300);');

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'DECLARE RowCursor CURSOR FOR ';
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ';';

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'OPEN RowCursor ';   
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'FETCH NEXT FROM RowCursor INTO ' + @ColumnsVar + '; ';
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 '  ;
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'BEGIN ';  

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO TARGETTABLE Values ' + @InsertValues + ';';

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'FETCH NEXT FROM RowCursor INTO ' + @ColumnsVar + '; ';
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'END ';   

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'CLOSE RowCursor ';   
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'DEALLOCATE RowCursor ';

exec(@SQL)
```